# SQL - Get all tuples with second element shared by all first element

Tags: sql

I have a table T, with 2 attributes clientid and productid. Each row represents a sell.

I have to find the number of products that have been bought by all client in my database.

I am new to SQL and I can't find an easy way of doing it.

Example:

```
clientid | productid
--------------------
1        | A
1        | B
1        | C
1        | D
2        | A
2        | C
2        | E
3        | A
3        | B
```

Expected Result:

```
Count: 1
```

because only product A has been bought by client 1, 2 and 3

Thanks

Comment: Post your sample data and expected result

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
select productid
from sales
group by productid
having count(*) = (select count(distinct clientid)
                   from sales);
```

The above will return all productids that are bought by all clients. If just need the count, wrap that into a derived table:

```
select count(*) 
from (
  select productid
  from sales
  group by productid
  having count(*) = (select count(distinct clientid)
                     from sales)
) t;
```

---

The above only returns products that have been bought by all clients that have ordered *at least* one product. If you have a `client` table where **all* clients are stored you should replace the sub-query with `select count(*) from clients`

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect